# Broadcast packets do not propagate through a Linux veth tunnel

Tags: linux, broadcast, broadcasting, virtual-network, virtual-network-interface

I am developing a networking application that relies on subnet broadcasting. I decided to set up a controlled environment for testing and development purposes on my local machine using virtual Ethernet interfaces (`veth`). The setup is straightforward:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ifconfig veth0 192.168.241.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig veth1 192.168.241.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

`ip link` confirms that the interfaces are up and that the broadcast flags are set:

```
8: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:29:76:81:27:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:ad:f9:cb:28:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

A trivial test in Python REPL shows that the interfaces are functional. This is the receiver:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.bind(('192.168.241.2', 48469))
>>> s.recvfrom(1000)
(b'abc', ('192.168.241.1', 45560))
```

And this is the sender:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.connect(('192.168.241.2', 48469))
>>> s.send(b'abc')
3
```

Works well for unicast packets. Broadcast packets, however, appear to be silently dropped. The following sender-side REPL can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
>>> s.connect(('192.168.241.255', 48469))
>>> s.send(b'abc')
3
>>> s  # For diagnostic purposes
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.241.1', 48065), raddr=('192.168.241.255', 48469)>
```

The socket is configured successfully, but the emitted broadcast packets never make it to the other side of the tunnel. This is not the behavior I expected, especially considering that the interface flags indicate that the interfaces support broadcasting. I am running these tests on Linux Mint 18 with a stock kernel. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The tunnel is fine.**

The problem was that Linux discards all incoming broadcast traffic unless the socket is bound to `INADDR_ANY`. If the receiver-side REPL is updated as follows, everything works:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.bind(('', 48469))  # Bind to INADDR_ANY to accept broadcast packets
>>> s.recvfrom(1000)
(b'abc', ('192.168.241.1', 45560))
```

On Windows, the behavior is different (irrespective of the tunnel): binding a socket to a specific interface does not reject broadcast traffic.

Man 7 IP says that `SO_BROADCAST` should be set in order to receive broadcast datagrams; however, the behavior I am observing on the receiving side does not seem to match the description:

> Datagrams to broadcast addresses can be sent or received only when the SO_BROADCAST socket flag is set.

Broadcast datagrams can always be received with `INADDR_ANY`; never if the socket is bound to a specific interface. Both statements hold irrespective of `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)`.